# Merge sliced lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list with N elements, and I slice it using certain step, let's say 3:

```
slice0 = text[0::3]
slice1 = text[1::3]
slice2 = text[2::3]
```

After doing some processing separatedly, now I'd need to merge them back in the same positions they were in the original list. Is there a similar (easy) way to do this?

Example:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6] -> L0 = [1,4], L1 = [2,5], L2 = [3,6]
```

Then some processing (say multiply each list by 1, 2 and 3 respectively:

```
L0 = [1,4], L1 = [4,10], L2 = [9,18]
```

Merge them back to their original positions

```
L = [1,4,9,4,10,18]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function to join them back together:

```
>>> l0 = [1,4]; l1 = [4,10]; l2 = [9,18]
>>> zip(l0, l1, l2)
[(1, 4, 9), (4, 10, 18)]
>>> [x for t in zip(l0, l1, l2) for x in t]
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18]
```

Or use [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*zip(l0, l1, l2)))
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18]
```

In Python 3, where `zip` is a generator function, [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) might be preferrable, as others have pointed out already.

Comment: Instead of `chain(*...)`, [chain.from_iterable](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) may be used (It'll be useful for Python 3.x, where `zip` is a generator).

Comment: @ovgolovin: Sure, that avoids the conversion into a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> L0 = [1,4]
>>> L1 = [4,10]
>>> L2 = [9,18]
>>> [x for zipped in zip(L0, L1, L2) for x in zipped]
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18]
```

Or an alternative using [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(L0, L1, L2)))
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> l0, l1, l2, = [1,4], [4,10], [9,18]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l0,l1,l2)))
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L0 = [1,4]
L1 = [4,10] 
L2 = [9,18]

#returns a tuple

my_data = sum(zip(L0,L1,L2),())

#or if you need a list

my_data = list(sum(zip(L0,L1,L2),()))
```

tuple:

```
>>> my_data
(1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18)
```

list:

```
>>> my_data
[1, 4, 9, 4, 10, 18]
```